# How to pause a leaflet panTo() animation

Tags: javascript, animation, events, leaflet, pause

I am trying to make a map that automatically pan to several locations, one after the other, using Leaflet 1.7.1. This is working quite well using the [`panTo()`](https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/reference.html#map-panto) function :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,body,#map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='map'></div>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var map = L.map('map');
var osm = new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
map.dragging.disable();
map.setView([48.980, 4.373], 7);

var athens = [37.9844, 23.7398]
var stockholm = [59.3272, 18.0830]

setTimeout(function() {
    map.panTo([athens[0], athens[1]], {
        animate: true,
        duration: 20,
        easeLinearity: 0.9
    })
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function() {
    map.panTo([stockholm[0], stockholm[1]], {
        animate: true,
        duration: 15,
        easeLinearity: 0.9
    })
}, 22000);
```

I would like to add a pause/resume function, but I cannot figure how to do this. I am able to stop the animation using the following command :

```
map.setView(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom(), {"animate": false});
```

But I cannot resume the animation afterwards, and the later timed panTo events will happen anyway.

Any leads or ideas on how to achieve that ?

Comment: Please, make a reproducible example is here